# How to simplifying this method in a Ruby-ish way?

Tags: ruby

I've recently been working on simplifying a Ruby method that I didn't write. It's part of a legacy project that a coworker wrote. In general, we did a pretty good job not accumulating code debt, but there are a few methods that need some love.

The method that I've been simplifying was originally a mass of nested if-else blocks. I determined what the method does and simplified the method so there are no longer nested ifs.

Now I want to simplify it even more, and, if possible, I want to eliminate all but one `return` statement. The method is longer than this, but this is the general concept of what it looks like right now:

```
def return_bool
  return false unless condition1 && condition2
  @var = SomeClass.getter(foo)
  return true unless var.someProperty != 0
  @stuff = @var.getsomething id
  return false unless @stuff && somethingElse
  data = JSON.parse(@stuff)
  @stuff.each do |stuff|
    return false if data[stuff['something']] != stuff['anotherSomething']
  end
  return true
end
```

I thought about using `raise` and exception handling to reduce `return` statements, but if, for example, `condition1` is false, it's not an exceptional situation, I expect it at certain times.

How can I reduce the number of `return` statements, preferably down to one? If possible, I'd actually prefer to implicitly return if I can.

Comment: `raise` is never better, than `return`

Comment: That actually does something useful?

Comment: @Greg Yes. Like I mentioned, it's a bigger method but I just wanted to post a small code sample so you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code isn't from something that works because Ruby would refuse to execute that method definition.

This is how I would unravel it, but without sample values for any of the local variables or the definition of `SomeClass` there's no way to test it.

```
def return_bool
  if (condition1 && condition2)
    @var = SomeClass.getter(foo)
    if (var.someProperty == 0)
      @stuff = @var.getsomething id
      if (! (@stuff && somethingElse))
        data = JSON.parse(@stuff)
        @stuff.each do |stuff|
          return false if data[stuff['something']] != stuff['anotherSomething']
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

Comment: This gives me some ideas to work off of. Thanks! +1 and accepted.

Comment: The #1 thing I saw in the original code is the horrid reliance on `unless`. It's equivalent to `if (!some_boolean_value)` but makes our brain work overtime decoding what is happening. By changing the statements using `unless` to `if (!...)` it looked like nested `if` statements would be close to the same logic.

Comment: @theTinMan I know I'm quite late, but the original code returns `false` when `condition1 && condition2` is `false`, while your code returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Use ExtractMethod to cut the method up in smaller logical parts. Your tests should help you make sure you don't break anything.
http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

```
  def return_bool
    some_condition? &&
       var_is_valid? &&
       stuff_is_valid? &&
       parsed_stuff_has_something?
  end

  def get_var
    @var = SomeClass.getter(foo)
  end

  def get_stuff
    @stuff = @var.getsomething id
  end

  def some_condition?
    condition1 && condition2
  end

  def var_is_valid?
    get_var.someProperty == 0
  end

  def stuff_is_valid?
    get_stuff && somethingElse
  end

  def parsed_stuff_has_something?
    data = JSON.parse(@stuff)
    @stuff.each do |stuff|
      return false if data[stuff['something']] != stuff['anotherSomething']
    end
    true
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.all?` instead of last `.each` loop:

```
def return_bool
  return false unless condition1 && condition2
  @var = SomeClass.getter foo
  return true unless var.someProperty != 0
  @stuff = @var.getsomething id
  return false unless somethingElse && @stuff
  data = JSON.parse @stuff
  @stuff.all? do |stuff|
    data[stuff['something']] == stuff['anotherSomething']
  end
end
```

By the way, *returns vs ifs* is like a holywar. I prefer returns.
Also, if you don't like returns, what about this?

```
def return_bool
  condition1 && condition2 && (
    @var = SomeClass.getter foo
    var.someProperty.zero? || (
      (@stuff = @var.getsomething id) && somethingElse && (
        data = JSON.parse @stuff
        @stuff.all? do |stuff|
          data[stuff['something']] == stuff['anotherSomething']
        end ) ) )
end
```

Comment: I have to think about this a bit, but if `somethingElse` is falsy, then `@stuff = ...` never gets evaluated, whereas in the original version the assignment *does* happen.

Comment: BTW: that double negation looks a bit nasty, how about `return true if var.someProperty.zero?`